# How to use JUnit to test asynchronous processes

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit

How do you test methods that fire asynchronous processes with JUnit?

I don't know how to make my test wait for the process to end (it is not exactly a unit test, it is more like an integration test as it involves several classes and not just one).

Comment: You could try JAT (Java Asynchronous Test): https://bitbucket.org/csolar/jat

Comment: JAT has 1 watcher and hasn't been updated in 1.5 years.  Awaitility was  updated just 1 month ago and is on version 1.6 at the time of this writing.  I'm not affiliated with either project, but if I was going to invest in an addition to my project, I'd give more credence to Awaitility at this time.

Comment: JAT has still no updates: "Last updated 2013-01-19". Just save the time to follow the link.

Comment: @LesHazlewood, one watcher is bad for JAT, but about no updates for years... Just one example. How often do you update low-level TCP stack of your OS, if it just works? Alternative to JAT is answered below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631598/how-to-use-junit-to-test-asynchronous-processes/3303638#3303638 .

Answer (score 50, accepted):

IMHO it's bad practice to have unit tests create or wait on threads, etc. You'd like these tests to run in split seconds. That's why I'd like to propose a 2-step approach to testing async processes.

1. Test that your async process is submitted properly. You can mock the object that accepts your async requests and make sure that the submitted job has correct properties, etc.
2. Test that your async callbacks are doing the right things. Here you can mock out the originally submitted job and assume it's initialized properly and verify that your callbacks are correct.

Comment: Sure. But sometimes you need to test code that is specifically supposed to manage threads.

Comment: I'm writing a messaging framework, it three layers, an application layer, a data access layer and the transport layer. Application layer handles the state of the signaling, data access layer handles addressing. These are independent of network technology, so I have my unit tests for them. I also have integration tests for the whole thing running on a memory based transport layer.
How can I test the network based transport layer? I can run it on loopback, having only milliseconds of latency, but that still is async.

Comment: For those of us that use Junit or TestNG to do integration testing (and not just unit testing), or user acceptance testing (e.g. w/ Cucumber), waiting for an async completion and verifying the result is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Asynchronous processes are some of the most complicated code to get right and you say you should not use unit testing for them and only test with a single thread? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: Mock tests often fail to prove that functionality works end to end. Async functionality needs to be tested in an asynchronous manner to insure it works. Call it an integration test if you prefer, but it's a test that is still needed.

Comment: I don´t agree that asynchronous code has to be tested in an asynchronous manner. For testing the logic and error cases it is totally fine to have the code run synchronous.

In my tests I mock all the asynchronous functions with a synchronous result. Like that I can test the functionality without having to care about asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: There are techniques that minimize "waiting for other threads", pretty much negating your view that this is a bad practice. An even worst practice is not testing this code. See Martin's answer for an example.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Testing goes beyond unit testing. The OP calls it out as more of an Integration Test than a Unit Test.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer - especially given its now 10 year age. See the other answers below for the correct solution.

Answer (score 231):

**TL;DR;** Unfortunately, there is no built-in solution **yet** (at time of writting, 2022), hence you are free to use and/or implement whatever fits your situation.

### Example

An alternative is to use the [CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class.

```
public class DatabaseTest {

    /**
     * Data limit
     */
    private static final int DATA_LIMIT = 5;

    /**
     * Countdown latch
     */
    private CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

    /**
     * Received data
     */
    private List<Data> receiveddata;

    @Test
    public void testDataRetrieval() throws Exception {
        Database db = new MockDatabaseImpl();
        db.getData(DATA_LIMIT, new DataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Data> data) {
                receiveddata = data;
                lock.countDown();
            }
        });

        lock.await(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        assertNotNull(receiveddata);
        assertEquals(DATA_LIMIT, receiveddata.size());
    }
}
```

**NOTE** you can't just used **syncronized** with a regular object as a lock, as fast callbacks can release the lock before the lock's wait method is called. See [this](http://joe.truemesh.com/blog/000279.html) blog post by Joe Walnes.

**EDIT** Removed syncronized blocks around CountDownLatch thanks to comments from @jtahlborn and @Ring

Comment: Nice decription of CountDownLatch @Raz

Comment: If you're verifying that onSuccess was called, you should assert that lock.await returns true.

Comment: I don't think this answer really resolve his problem. This answer It's an alternative if the developer can pass a CountDownLatch as parameter to another thread make the countDown(), what is not always possible.

Comment: I would remove the timeout from the `await()` call. Using `CountDownLatch` should guarantee that you'll get the result "as soon as possible", rendering it unecessary.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy I think I put it there in case your lock.countDown didn't run. Without it you could potentially have a hung test.

Comment: @Martin that would be correct, but it would mean you have a different problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: the problem is that it will wait for the last line of the method to be reached and not for the method to exit. This is a huge difference. For example if the method has some annotations on it like transactional then it is possible that the test will finish the await but the transaction havent finished at all.

Answer (score 98):

You can try using the [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) library. It makes it easy to test the systems you're talking about.

Comment: A friendly disclaimer: Johan is the main contributor to the project.

Comment: Suffers from the fundamental problem of having to *wait* (unit tests need to run *fast*). Ideally you really don't want to wait a millisecond longer than needed, so I think using `CountDownLatch` (see answer by @Martin) is better in this regard.

Comment: This is the perfect library that fulfills my async process integration test requirements. Really awesome. The library seems to be well maintained and has features extending from basic to advanced that I believe are sufficient to cater for most scenarios. Thanks for the awesome reference!

Answer (score 93):

If you use a [CompletableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (introduced in Java 8) or a [SettableFuture](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) (from [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)), you can make your test finish as soon as it's done, rather than waiting a pre-set amount of time.  Your test would look something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {         
    @Override
    public void run() {
        future.complete("Hello World!");                
    }
});
assertEquals("Hello World!", future.get());
```

> **Note** that there is a library which Provides `CompletableFuture` for pre Java-8, which even uses the same names (and provides all related Java-8 classes), like:
>
> ```
> net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport-minifuture:1.7.4
> ```
>
> This is useful for Android development, where even if we build with JDK-v11, we want to keep codes compatible with pre Android-7 devices.

Comment: ... and if you're stuck with java-less-than-eight try guavas [SettableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) which does pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 25):

Start the process off and wait for the result using a [`Future`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: For those wondering, just use the `get()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()).

Answer (score 21):

One method I've found pretty useful for testing asynchronous methods is injecting an `Executor` instance in the object-to-test's constructor. In production, the executor instance is configured to run asynchronously while in test it can be mocked to run synchronously.

So suppose I'm trying to test the asynchronous method `Foo#doAsync(Callback c)`,

```
class Foo {
  private final Executor executor;
  public Foo(Executor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  public void doAsync(Callback c) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        // Do stuff here
        c.onComplete(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In production, I would construct `Foo` with an `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` Executor instance  while in test I would probably construct it with a synchronous executor that does the following --

```
class SynchronousExecutor implements Executor {
  @Override public void execute(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
  }
}
```

Now my JUnit test of the asynchronous method is pretty clean --

```
@Test public void testDoAsync() {
  Executor executor = new SynchronousExecutor();
  Foo objectToTest = new Foo(executor);

  Callback callback = mock(Callback.class);
  objectToTest.doAsync(callback);

  // Verify that Callback#onComplete was called using Mockito.
  verify(callback).onComplete(any(Data.class));

  // Assert that we got back the data that we expected.
  assertEquals(expectedData, callback.getData());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if I want to integration test something that involves an asynchronous library call like Spring's `WebClient`

Answer (score 8):

JUnit 5 has `Assertions.assertTimeout(Duration, Executable)`/`assertTimeoutPreemptively()`(please read Javadoc of each to understand the difference) and Mockito has `verify(mock, timeout(millisecs).times(x))`.

```
Assertions.assertTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000), () -> 
    myReactiveService.doSth().subscribe()
);
```

And:

```
Mockito.verify(myReactiveService, 
    timeout(1000).times(0)).doSth(); // cannot use never() here
```

Timeout may be nondeterministic/fragile in pipelines. So be careful.

Answer (score 4):

How about calling `SomeObject.wait` and `notifyAll` as described [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596003870/junit/jextprockbk-chp-4-sect-15) OR using **Robotiums** `Solo.waitForCondition(...)` method OR use a [class i wrote](https://github.com/doridori/AndroidUtilDump/blob/master/android/AndroidUtilDump/src/couk/doridori/android/lib/testing/FutureAsyncTester.java) to do this (see comments and test class for how to use)

Comment: The problem with the wait/notify/interrupt approach is that the code you're testing can potentially interfere with the waiting threads (I've seen it happen). This is why [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit) uses a private [circuit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jodah/concurrentunit/Waiter.java#L18) that threads can wait on, which cannot be inadvertently interfered with by interrupts to the main test thread.

Answer (score 4):

I find an library [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) to test asynchronous logic. It looks simple and brief way using [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). Here is [example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/master/src/test/java/io/socket/client/ServerConnectionTest.java):

```
    @Test(timeout = TIMEOUT)
public void message() throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    final BlockingQueue<Object> values = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();

    socket = client();
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... objects) {
            socket.send("foo", "bar");
        }
    }).on(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            values.offer(args);
        }
    });
    socket.connect();

    assertThat((Object[])values.take(), is(new Object[] {"hello client"}));
    assertThat((Object[])values.take(), is(new Object[] {"foo", "bar"}));
    socket.disconnect();
}
```

Using LinkedBlockingQueue take API to block until to get result just like synchronous way. And set timeout to avoid assuming too much time to wait the result.

Comment: Awesome approach!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning that there is very useful chapter `Testing Concurrent Programs` in [Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004V9OA84) which describes some unit testing approaches and gives solutions for issues.

Comment: Which approach is that? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

For all Spring users out there, this is how I usually do my integration tests nowadays, where async behaviour is involved:

Fire an application event in production code, when an async task (such as an I/O call) has finished. Most of the time this event is necessary anyway to handle the response of the async operation in production.

With this event in place, you can then use the following strategy in your test case:

1. Execute the system under test
2. Listen for the event and make sure that the event has fired
3. Do your assertions

To break this down, you'll first need some kind of domain event to fire. I'm using a UUID here to identify the task that has completed, but you're of course free to use something else as long as it's unique.

(Note, that the following code snippets also use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotations to get rid of boiler plate code)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class TaskCompletedEvent() {
  private final UUID taskId;
  // add more fields containing the result of the task if required
}
```

The production code itself then typically looks like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Production {

  private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

  void doSomeTask(UUID taskId) {
    // do something like calling a REST endpoint asynchronously
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(new TaskCompletedEvent(taskId));
  }

}
```

I can then use a Spring `@EventListener` to catch the published event in test code. The event listener is a little bit more involved, because it has to handle two cases in a thread safe manner:

1. Production code is faster than the test case and the event has already fired before the test case checks for the event, or
2. Test case is faster than production code and the test case has to wait for the event.

A `CountDownLatch` is used for the second case as mentioned in other answers here. Also note, that the `@Order` annotation on the event handler method makes sure, that this event handler method gets called after any other event listeners used in production.

```
@Component
class TaskCompletionEventListener {

  private Map<UUID, CountDownLatch> waitLatches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private List<UUID> eventsReceived = new ArrayList<>();

  void waitForCompletion(UUID taskId) {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (eventAlreadyReceived(taskId)) {
        return;
      }
      checkNobodyIsWaiting(taskId);
      createLatch(taskId);
    }
    waitForEvent(taskId);
  }

  private void checkNobodyIsWaiting(UUID taskId) {
    if (waitLatches.containsKey(taskId)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only one waiting test per task ID supported, but another test is already waiting for " + taskId + " to complete.");
    }
  }

  private boolean eventAlreadyReceived(UUID taskId) {
    return eventsReceived.remove(taskId);
  }

  private void createLatch(UUID taskId) {
    waitLatches.put(taskId, new CountDownLatch(1));
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  private void waitForEvent(UUID taskId) {
    var latch = waitLatches.get(taskId);
    latch.await();
  }

  @EventListener
  @Order
  void eventReceived(TaskCompletedEvent event) {
    var taskId = event.getTaskId();
    synchronized (this) {
      if (isSomebodyWaiting(taskId)) {
        notifyWaitingTest(taskId);
      } else {
        eventsReceived.add(taskId);
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean isSomebodyWaiting(UUID taskId) {
    return waitLatches.containsKey(taskId);
  }

  private void notifyWaitingTest(UUID taskId) {
    var latch = waitLatches.remove(taskId);
    latch.countDown();
  }

}
```

Last step is to execute the system under test in a test case. I'm using a SpringBoot test with JUnit 5 here, but this should work the same for all tests using a Spring context.

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProductionIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private Production sut;

  @Autowired
  private TaskCompletionEventListener listener;

  @Test
  void thatTaskCompletesSuccessfully() {
    var taskId = UUID.randomUUID();
    sut.doSomeTask(taskId);
    listener.waitForCompletion(taskId);
    // do some assertions like looking into the DB if value was stored successfully
  }

}
```

Note, that in contrast to other answers here, this solution will also work if you execute your tests in parallel and multiple threads exercise the async code at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using nowadays if the test result is produced asynchronously.

```
public class TestUtil {

    public static <R> R await(Consumer<CompletableFuture<R>> completer) {
        return await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, completer);
    }

    public static <R> R await(int time, TimeUnit unit, Consumer<CompletableFuture<R>> completer) {
        CompletableFuture<R> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
        completer.accept(f);
        try {
            return f.get(time, unit);
        } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Future timed out", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Future failed", e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

Using static imports, the test reads kinda nice.
(note, in this example I'm starting a thread to illustrate the idea)

```
    @Test
    public void testAsync() {
        String result = await(f -> {
            new Thread(() -> f.complete("My Result")).start();
        });
        assertEquals("My Result", result);
    }
```

If `f.complete` isn't called, the test will fail after a timeout. You can also use `f.completeExceptionally` to fail early.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers here but a simple one is to just create a completed CompletableFuture and use it:

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture("donzo")
```

So in my test:

```
this.exactly(2).of(mockEventHubClientWrapper).sendASync(with(any(LinkedList.class)));
this.will(returnValue(new CompletableFuture<>().completedFuture("donzo")));
```

I am just making sure all of this stuff gets called anyway.  This technique works if you are using this code:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(calls.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```

It will zip right through it as all the CompletableFutures are finished!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid testing with parallel threads whenever you can (which is most of the time). This will only make your tests flaky (sometimes pass, sometimes fail).

Only when you need to call some other library / system, you might have to wait on other threads, in that case always use the [Awaitility](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/) library instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

Never just call `get()` or `join()` in your tests, else your tests might run forever on your CI server in case the future never completes. Always assert `isDone()` first in your tests before calling `get()`. For CompletionStage, that is `.toCompletableFuture().isDone()`.

When you test a non-blocking method like this:

```
public static CompletionStage<String> createGreeting(CompletableFuture<String> future) {
    return future.thenApply(result -> "Hello " + result);
}
```

then you should not just test the result by passing a completed Future in the test, you should also make sure that your method `doSomething()` does not block by calling `join()` or `get()`. This is important in particular if you use a non-blocking framework.

To do that, test with a non-completed future that you set to completed manually:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> innerFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<String> futureResult = createGreeting(innerFuture).toCompletableFuture();
    assertFalse(futureResult.isDone());

    // this triggers the future to complete
    innerFuture.complete("world");
    assertTrue(futureResult.isDone());

    // futher asserts about fooResult here
    assertEquals(futureResult.get(), "Hello world");
}
```

That way, if you add `future.join()` to doSomething(), the test will fail.

If your Service uses an ExecutorService such as in `thenApplyAsync(..., executorService)`, then in your tests inject a single-threaded ExecutorService, such as the one from guava:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

If your code uses the forkJoinPool such as `thenApplyAsync(...)`, rewrite the code to use an ExecutorService (there are many good reasons), or use Awaitility.

To shorten the example, I made BarService a method argument implemented as a Java8 lambda in the test, typically it would be an injected reference that you would mock.

Comment: Hey @tkruse, perhaps do you have a public git repo with a test using this technique ?

Comment: @Christiano: that would be against SO philosophy. Instead, I changed the methods to compile without any additional code (all imports are java8+ or junit) when you paste them into an empty junit test class. Feel free to upvote.

Comment: I understood now. thanks. My problem now is to test when the methods returns CompletableFuture but do accept other objects as parameters other than a CompletableFuture.

Comment: In your case, who creates the CompletableFuture that the method returns? If it is another service, that can be mocked and my technique still applies. If the method itself creates a CompletableFuture the situation changes very much so you could ask a new question about it. It then depends on what thread will complete the future that your method returns.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use wait and notify. It is simple and clear.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Throwable {
    final boolean[] asyncExecuted = {false};
    final Throwable[] asyncThrowable= {null};

    // do anything async
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Put your test here.
                fail(); 
            }
            // lets inform the test thread that there is an error.
            catch (Throwable throwable){
                asyncThrowable[0] = throwable;
            }
            // ensure to release asyncExecuted in case of error.
            finally {
                synchronized (asyncExecuted){
                    asyncExecuted[0] = true;
                    asyncExecuted.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // Waiting for the test is complete
    synchronized (asyncExecuted){
        while(!asyncExecuted[0]){
            asyncExecuted.wait();
        }
    }

    // get any async error, including exceptions and assertationErrors
    if(asyncThrowable[0] != null){
        throw asyncThrowable[0];
    }
}
```

Basically, we need to create a final Array reference, to be used inside of anonymous inner class. I would rather create a boolean[], because I can put a value to control if we need to wait(). When everything is done, we just release the asyncExecuted.

Comment: If your assertion fails, the main test thread won't know about it.

Comment: Thanks for solution, helps me to debug code with websocket connection.

Comment: @Jonathan, I updated the code to catch any assertion and exception and inform it to the main test thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the logic just don´t test it asynchronously.

For example to test this code which works on results of an asynchronous method.

```
public class Example {
    private Dependency dependency;

    public Example(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;            
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> someAsyncMethod(){
        return dependency.asyncMethod()
                .handle((r,ex) -> {
                    if(ex != null) {
                        return "got exception";
                    } else {
                        return r.toString();
                    }
                });
    }
}

public class Dependency {
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> asyncMethod() {
        // do some async stuff       
    }
}
```

In the test mock the dependency with synchronous implementation. The unit test is completely synchronous and runs in 150ms.

```
public class DependencyTest {
    private Example sut;
    private Dependency dependency;

    public void setup() {
        dependency = Mockito.mock(Dependency.class);;
        sut = new Example(dependency);
    }

    @Test public void success() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        when(dependency.asyncMethod()).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(5));

        // When
        CompletableFuture<String> result = sut.someAsyncMethod();

        // Then
        assertThat(result.isCompletedExceptionally(), is(equalTo(false)));
        String value = result.get();
        assertThat(value, is(equalTo("5")));
    }

    @Test public void failed() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // Given
        CompletableFuture<Integer> c = new CompletableFuture<Integer>();
        c.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("failed"));
        when(dependency.asyncMethod()).thenReturn(c);

        // When
        CompletableFuture<String> result = sut.someAsyncMethod();

        // Then
        assertThat(result.isCompletedExceptionally(), is(equalTo(false)));
        String value = result.get();
        assertThat(value, is(equalTo("got exception")));
    }
}
```

You don´t test the async behaviour but you can test if the logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this code:

```
public void method() {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            //logic
            //logic
            //logic
            //logic
        });
    }
```

Try to refactor it to something like this:

```
public void refactoredMethod() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::subMethod);
}

private void subMethod() {
    //logic
    //logic
    //logic
    //logic
}
```

After that, test the subMethod this way:

```
org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(classInstance, "subMethod");
```

This isn't a perfect solution, but it tests all the logic inside your async execution.

Comment: This solution is better if `subMethod` is extracted to another class, and thus can be tested without powermock/reflection

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is explained in the code, there are two different approaches depending on your needs.

```java
package es.victorherraiz.learningjava;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.timeout;

@ExtendWith(AsyncTest.AsyncExtension.class)
public class AsyncTest {


    /**
     * This first test uses a custom extension, the code is down there.
     * It is useful when there are plenty of async tests
     * @param cb The callback
     */
    @Test
    void test1(AsyncCallback cb) {
        cb.setTimeout(5000);
        delayedExecutor(2000, MILLISECONDS)
            .execute(cb::success);
    }

    /**
     * This test uses mockito, it is slower to detect signal.
     * Use this when there are only a few async tests.
     */
    @Test
    void test2() {
        var mock = mock(Runnable.class);
        delayedExecutor(2000, MILLISECONDS)
            .execute(mock);
        then(mock).should(timeout(5000)).run();
    }

    public static final class AsyncCallback {
        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        private final AtomicLong timeout = new AtomicLong(5000);
        private Exception exception;

        private void setTimeout(long timeout) {
            this.timeout.set(timeout);
        }

        private long getTimeout() {
            return this.timeout.get();
        };


        boolean await() throws InterruptedException {
            return latch.await(timeout.get(), MILLISECONDS);
        }

        Exception getFailure() {
            return exception;
        }

        public void done(Exception exception) {
            this.exception = exception;
            latch.countDown();
        }

        public void success() {
            done(null);
        }

        public void failure(Exception exception) {
            done(exception);
        }
    }

    // Extract this class to any common package
    public static class AsyncExtension implements ParameterResolver, AfterTestExecutionCallback {
        private static final ExtensionContext.Namespace NAMESPACE =
            ExtensionContext.Namespace.create(AsyncExtension.class);

        @Override
        public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
            return parameterContext.getParameter().getType().equals(AsyncCallback.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
            return extensionContext.getStore(NAMESPACE).getOrComputeIfAbsent(AsyncCallback.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
            var callback = (AsyncCallback) extensionContext.getStore(NAMESPACE).get(AsyncCallback.class);
            if (callback != null) {
                if (!callback.await()) {
                    throw new TimeoutException("Timeout: there was not signal for " + callback.getTimeout() + "ms");
                }
                var failure = callback.getFailure();
                if (failure != null) {
                    throw failure;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```