# Project Reactor: wait while broadcaster finish

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, project-reactor, reactive-streams

There is a Broadcaster, that accepts strings and append them to a StringBuilder.

I want to test it.

I have to use `Thread#sleep` to wait, while the broadcaster finish processing of strings. I want to remove `sleep`.

I tried to use `Control#debug()` unsuccessfully.

```
public class BroadcasterUnitTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    //prepare
    Environment.initialize();
    Broadcaster<String> sink = Broadcaster.create(Environment.newDispatcher()); //run broadcaster in separate thread (dispatcher)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sink
            .observe(s -> sleep(100)) //long-time operation
            .consume(sb::append);

    //do
    sink.onNext("a");
    sink.onNext("b");

    //assert
    sleep(500);//wait while broadcaster finished (if comment this line then the test will fail)
    assertEquals("ab", sb.toString());
}

private void sleep(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `Broadcaster` (and it's probably deprecated since the question is old), but these 3 ways could be helpful in general:

1. When testing `Project-Reactor`'s `Flux`es and stuff, you're probably better of using their testing library made specially for this. [Their reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#testing) and the [Javadoc](http://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/) on that part are pretty good, and I'll just copy an example that speaks for itself here:

   ```
   @Test
   public void testAppendBoomError() {
     Flux<String> source = Flux.just("foo", "bar"); 
     StepVerifier.create( 
       appendBoomError(source)) 
       .expectNext("foo") 
       .expectNext("bar")
       .expectErrorMessage("boom") 
       .verify(); 
   }
   ```
2. You could just `block()` by yourself on the `Flux`es and `Mono`s and then run checks. And note that if an error is emitted, this will result in  an exception. But have a feeling  you'll find yourself needing to write more code for some cases (e.g., checking the `Flux` has emitted 2 items `X` & `Y` then terminated with error) and you'd be then re-implementing `StepVerifier`.

   ```
   @Test
   public void testFluxOrMono() {
     Flux<String> source = Flux.just(2, 3);
     List<Integer> result = source
           .flatMap(i -> multiplyBy2Async(i))
           .collectList()
           .block();
     // run your asserts on the list. Reminder: the order may not be what you expect because of the `flatMap`
     // Or with a Mono:
     Integer resultOfMono = Mono.just(5)
           .flatMap(i -> multiplyBy2Async(i))
           .map(i -> i * 4)
           .block();
     // run your asserts on the integer
   }
   ```
3. You could use the general solutions to async testing like [CountDownLatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829949/6690391), but, again, wouldn't recommend and would give you trouble in some cases. For example, if you don't know the number of receivers in advance you'll need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Per answer above, I found `blockLast()` helped.

```
@Test
public void MyTest()
{
    Logs.Info("Start test");    
 
    /* 1 */
    // Make a request
    WebRequest wr1 = new WebRequest("1", "2", "3", "4");
    String json1 = wr1.toJson(wr1);
    
    Logs.Info("Flux");
    Flux<String> responses = controller.getResponses(json1);

    /* 2 */
    Logs.Info("Responses in");
    responses.subscribe(s -> mySub.myMethod(s)); // Test for strings is in myMethod
    
    Logs.Info("Test thread sleeping");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    /* 3 */
    Logs.Info("Test thread blocking");
    responses.blockLast();
    
    Logs.Info("Finish test");
}
```