# Unit test code inside of CompletableFuture runAsync

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit4, completable-future

There is a code written by someone who had called completable future to do an activity that is a call and forget i.e. output is not looked after (no `get()` call).

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            List<ActivityListTO> activities = auditCount(requestType, oldLimit, rule, newLimit);
            few mores lines here. 
...
, executor);
```

I was unit testing this but unable to execute the code inside of async.
I cannot static mock it as I need to execute the code inside it. I tried passing the thread pool instance in my testcase but it did not go.

Could you provide me some hints on how can I unit test the code inside async?

Comment: Simplest would probably be to wrap the `runAsync()` code in a separate service, and mock that service. This way you could even test the lambda itself independently.

Comment: Yes, This is one of the option but There has been guideline not to change the existing code. any other option do you see to get this working?

Comment: You can inject a custom Executor Instance and then do something like described in the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631598/how-to-use-junit-to-test-asynchronous-processes