# How to wait for X milliseconds in an Android Test?

Tags: android, junit

I am trying to test that a class that handles some animation change the value of a given object in `x` amount of milliseconds.

The test I want to do is "simple"

1. check that after `totalAnimationDuration / 2` the current value is bigger than the initial value
2. check that after `totalAnimationDuration` the value is the one I wanted.

My test looks now something like this:

```
    fun start() {
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            val linearAnimation = LinearAnimation()
            linearAnimation.start("Name", 0f, 1f, ::setValueTester)
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            assertEquals(1, currentValue)
        }

    }
```

The problem I have if that `Thread.sleep(2000)`sleeps the test it self so the complete animation inside `start` happens after the `sleep` and `assert`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JUnit to test asynchronous processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631598/how-to-use-junit-to-test-asynchronous-processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing the sleep on the wrong thread. This is my working solution:

```
    fun start() {
        // Test Thread
        val linearAnimation = LinearAnimation()

        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {    
        // Ui Thread
            linearAnimation.start("Name", 0f, 1f, ::setValueTester)
        }
        
        // Sleep the Test thread until the UI thread is done
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        assertEquals(1, currentValue)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Handler and postDelayed instead of Thread.sleep().

e.g.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
TODO("Do something")
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) to your project and express your expectation like the following:

```
fun start() {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
        val linearAnimation = LinearAnimation()
        linearAnimation.start("Name", 0f, 1f, ::setValueTester)
        await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until{ assertEquals(1, currentValue) }

    }

}
```

PS: Awaitility also provides a [Kotlin DSL](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Kotlin).

Comment: I would like to use this solution but sadly I can not add more dependencies to the project I am working at.